# HTML Table width in percentage, table rows separated equally

Tags: html, html-table

When I create a table in html, a table with a width of 100%, if I want all the cells (tds) to be divided in equal parts, do I have to enter the width % for each cell? Am I "obliged" to do it?

E.g.:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
   <tr>
      <td width="25%"></td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
      <td width="25%"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

OR the following could also be the right procedure, not to write the width in each tds if I want each of them to be devided equally:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I know it works with both manners but I just want to know the "legit" way to do it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to enter the width % for each cell. But wait, there's a better way to do that, it's called CSS:

```
<style>
     .equalDivide tr td { width:25%; }
</style>

<table class="equalDivide" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Interesting thank you. So if I have a table divided in 3 cells, I cannot use css width property and I have to use the old method is that it?

Comment: Why not? With 3 cell, you just need to change the width in percentage to 33% instead of 25%. Not absolutely perfect, but almost.

Comment: And if I have dynamic content, and do not know how much space the content would take, is it ok not to enter the widths and leave the browser dynamically divide the cells with the space they take?

Comment: a/ If you don't know how many cell you're dealng with, but still want to keep them equal, I'll help you with javascript. b/ If you don't specify the width, then the browser will devides the space in order to make the table's height smallest. (So, the cell with much data would be larger than the cell with less data)

Comment: sadly, Outlook still pushes ancestral practices for emailing...

Answer (score 49):

Use the property `table-layout:fixed;` on the table to get equally spaced cells. If a column has a width set, then no matter what the content is, it will be the specified width. Columns without a width set will divide whatever room is left over among themselves.

```
<table style='table-layout:fixed;'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>gobble de gook</td>
            <td>mibs</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Just to throw it out there, you could also use `<colgroup><col span='#' style='width:#%;'/></colgroup>`, which doesn't require repetition of style per table data or giving the table an id to use in a style sheet. I think setting the widths on the first row is enough though.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Will keep equal widths no matter how many cells are within the row.

Comment: `<colgroup>` deprecated in HTML4.01, obsolete in HTML5 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup

Comment: Several attributes of `colgroup` and `col` are deprecated, but the tags themselves and their `span` attributes are not. The attributes were likely deprecated due to them all being purely stylistic, which is what CSS is for, while `span` is necessary for showing the correct structure, regardless of whether CSS is present.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to specify the width for each cell, otherwise they will try to be "intelligent" about it and divide the 100% between whichever cells think they need it most.  Cells with more content will take up more width than those with less.

To make sure you get equal width for each cell you need to make it clear. Either do it as you already have, or use CSS.

```
table.className td { width: 25%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, I would do it with CSS, but i think you want it with tables without CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <body leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1" height="350px"> 
         <tr>
            <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
      </table> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely the cleanest answer to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14025331/1008519.
In combination with `table-layout: fixed` I often find `<colgroup>` a great tool to make columns act as you want (see [codepen here](http://codepen.io/mlunoe/pen/MJgmeP)):

```css
table {
 /* When set to 'fixed', all columns that do not have a width applied will get the remaining space divided between them equally */
 table-layout: fixed;
}
.fixed-width {
  width: 100px;
}
.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-11 {
  width: 91.666666667%;
}
.col-10 {
  width: 83.333333333%;
}
.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.col-8 {
  width: 66.666666667%;
}
.col-7 {
  width: 58.333333333%;
}
.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-5 {
  width: 41.666666667%;
}
.col-4 {
  width: 33.333333333%;
}
.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-2 {
  width: 16.666666667%;
}
.col-1 {
  width: 8.3333333333%;
}

/* Stylistic improvements from here */

.align-left {
  text-align: left;
}
.align-right {
  text-align: right;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table > tbody > tr > td,
table > thead > tr > th {
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <colgroup>
    <col /> <!-- take up rest of the space -->
    <col class="fixed-width" /> <!-- fixed width -->
    <col class="col-3" /> <!-- percentage width -->
    <col /> <!-- take up rest of the space -->
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="align-left">Title</th>
      <th class="align-right">Count</th>
      <th class="align-left">Name</th>
      <th class="align-left">Single</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-left">This is a very looooooooooong title that may break into multiple lines</td>
      <td class="align-right">19</td>
      <td class="align-left">Lisa McArthur</td>
      <td class="align-left">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-left">This is a shorter title</td>
      <td class="align-right">2</td>
      <td class="align-left">John Oliver Nielson McAllister</td>
      <td class="align-left">Yes</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <!-- define everything with percentage width -->
  <colgroup>
    <col class="col-6" />
    <col class="col-1" />
    <col class="col-4" />
    <col class="col-1" />
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="align-left">Title</th>
      <th class="align-right">Count</th>
      <th class="align-left">Name</th>
      <th class="align-left">Single</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-left">This is a very looooooooooong title that may break into multiple lines</td>
      <td class="align-right">19</td>
      <td class="align-left">Lisa McArthur</td>
      <td class="align-left">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-left">This is a shorter title</td>
      <td class="align-right">2</td>
      <td class="align-left">John Oliver Nielson McAllister</td>
      <td class="align-left">Yes</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `colgroup` is deprecated since HTML4.01 and obsolete in HTML5. My understanding is that we should use `td:nth-of-type(3)` in CSS instead.

Comment: There are a number of attributes on the `colgroup` tag that have been deprecated, but not `colgroup` itself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup
W3 recommends using CSS instead of these (including `width`): https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20100624/colgroup.html

I'll update the answer accordingly