# Bootstrap table column with weight

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid-layout

I have a table where I would like to specify which columns are more important and should be wider than the others.

I could do this using the grid system where I can specify the importance of some cells giving them more column space. However I would lose some benefits like the hoover effect, alternate row colors, etc.

Is there any way to make certain table columns have a higher width preference?

Answer (score 0):

You can give width seperatly. here is an already discussed link about width 
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700534/html-table-width-in-percentage-table-rows-separated-equaly)